# Unable to resolve file in public folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following a tutorial series online. I have my images and videos in the public folder and it unable to be resolved by background-image: url as below:

```
  .services {
    background-image: url('./images/img-2.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 100px;
  }
```

The error is shown as below:

```
./src/App.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/App.css)
Error: Can't resolve './images/img-2.jpg' in 'C:\Users\Ankit\Desktop\ReactJSPractice\travel-practice\src'
```

I tried moving this folder to src but then my other images being called by React code directly don't work. This example below fails if I add images in src

```
<CardItem 
    src='images/img-2.jpg'
    text='Travel through the Islands of Bali in a private cruise'
    label='Luxury'
    path='/services'
/>
```

I can put the images in both the places but that is not an ideal solution.

I tried looking for it on the internet and some solutions suggest reverting react-scripts to 3.x.x  and adding an .env file but it no longer works in 4.x.x.

There has to be another solution which works in code. Below is my package.json if required:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
```

Comment: Well that is what I am trying to do but I want to use in the .services css class as you can see in the first code snippet, but I fails with the error mentioned above. The ./images/img-2.jpg refers to image in the public folder

Comment: You can not reference images outside *src* folder from CSS in react.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not reference images outside src folder from CSS in react. but you can reference it using inline styles.

`<Component style={{backgroundImage:"url(/images/img-2.jpg)"}} />`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. It fixed my code as I wished it